# how to swap array-elements to transfer the array from a column-like into a row-like representation

Tags: c++, algorithm, arrays

For example: the array

```
a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3
```

represents following table

```
a1, b1, c1, d1
a2, b2, c2, d2
a3, b3, c3, d3
```

now i like to bring the array into following form

```
a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, c3, d3
```

Does an algorithm exist, which takes the array (from the first form) and the dimensions of the table as input arguments and which transfers the array into the second form?
I thougt of an algorithm which doesn't need to allocate additional memory, instead i think it should be possible to do the job with element-swap operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you're looking for is *in-place matrix transpose*, and here's [an implementation](http://cheshirekow.com/blog/?p=4).

Comment: Your link is dead and the wayback machine doesn't seem to have a backup.

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing more than an [in-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition). Some pseudo-code:

```
for n = 0 to N - 2
    for m = n + 1 to N - 1
        swap A(n,m) with A(m,n)
```

As you can see, you'll need 2 indices to access an element. This can be done by transforming `(n,m)` to `nP+m` with `P` being the number of columns.

Comment: Is there an M missing?  I don't see how your pseudo code stays away from swapping already swapped elements...

Comment: It's for square matrices. The article contains references for rectangular matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia devotes an article to this process, which is called In-place Matrix Transposition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Answer (score 4):

Why bother?  If they are laid out in a 1-D array and you know how many elements there are in a logical row/span then you can get sequentially at any index with a little arithmetic.

```
int index(int row, int col, int elements)
{
  return ((row * elements) + col);
}

int inverted_index(int row, int col, int elements)
{
  return ((col * elements) + row);
}
```

then when you access the elements you can say something like...

```
array[index(row, col, elements)];
array[inverted_index(row, col, elements)];
```

I do most of my basic array manipulation like this for precisely the reason that I can transpose a matrix just by indexing it differently without any memory shuffling.  It is also just about the fastest thing you can do with a computer.

You can follow the same principle and address your first array in terms that meet the needs of your final example with some of your own arithmetic.

Comment: Depending on the memory access pattern there is a good reason for transposing a matrix. A matrix multiplication for instance can experience a speed-up by tranposing before multiplication, an article about this: http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/

Comment: I don't doubt it, however I bet that there will be just as much - if not more - access of the matrix elements in some other sequential way for purposes such as persistence and reporting.  If you look at the pattern in the OP's question I think an arithmetic scheme would work well.  Transpose if you like, I don't hold a religious opinion about it.

Comment: For SSE operations transpose is required, for example in a 2D separable blur filter.