# swapping an inner and outer vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, matrix

I have a vector of vector of myObjects defined, creating essentially a 2D array. I would like to transpose this array such that rows become columns and columns become rows. Obviously I could do this in a double for-loop, but this seems massively inelegant and will be pretty slow. I was wondering if there's something clever in C++ or the STL that would let me swap the inner and outer vectors around quickly and efficiently, rather than writing...

```
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < nRows; ++iRow)
{
      for (int iCol = 0; iCol < nCols; ++iCol)
      {
         myNew2DArray[iCol][iRow] = myOriginal2DArray[iRow][iCol];
      }
}
```

Comment: What's so massively inelegant about it? There's no getting around that you're going to have to move this memory.

Comment: Instead of making a new vector could you not do a bunch of swaps? Not sure what would be faster. Another alternative to transposition might be just to create a function that inverts the indices for you -- that way you could use it as if it were transposed.

Comment: @mwd: With the "bunch of swaps" you probably mean [In-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition). I once asked the question [how to swap array-elements to transfer the array from a column-like into a row-like representation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3009379/237483).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. It's not really clear what your constraints and goals are though (e.g. does space matter?). Is this purely a style/syntax question?

Comment: I've seen questions on here before about how to rotate indexing of ND-arrays using boost::extents but can't recall much about it

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can store the matrix in a vector and have a flag that specifies whether the matrix is transposed or not. Then you simply calculate the index. Here is an example:

```
class Matrix {
private:
    std::vector<int> matrix;
    bool isTransposed = false;
    int width, height;

public:
    // ...

    int getElement(int x, int y)
    {
        int w = width;
        int h = height;

        if(isTransposed) {
            int z = x;
            x = y;
            y = x;

            z = w;
            w = h;
            h = z;
        }

        return matrix[y * width + x];
    }

    // ...
};
```

This will reduce the cost of transposing the matrix, but increases the cost of actually accessing the elements.

Comment: The question is, what happens more often, accessing an element or transposing?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make a class called `Matrix` that contains the matrix that you are talking about.  Give the class a function `transpose()` that toggles a state flag for the state "transposed".  Then, overload the [] operator to follow mwd's suggestion of inverting the indeces when the matrix is in the transposed state.

Answer (score 0):

What you've coded already is pretty much the easiest way. Really you don't need a vector of vectors. You can just append each new 'row' to a single vector. Then what would have been element matrix[i][j] in your original vector of vectors is now matrix[(i*n)+j], when n is the 'width' of your matrix. The fiddly part is coming up with the algorithm to perform the transpose. I'm not saying this way is any better, but it's an alternative route, and what you've got already is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using the Eigen matrix library, which stores the transposedness property in a parameter of the matrix class. If that is not an option, google for one of the numerous matrix transpose algorithms.