# In-place transposition of a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Is it possible to transpose a `(m,n)` matrix in-place, giving that the matrix is represented as a single array of size `m*n` ?

The usual algorithm

```
transpose(Matrix mat,int rows, int cols ){
    //construction step
    Matrix tmat;
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
       tmat[j][i] = mat[i][j];
      }
    }
 }
```

doesn't apply to a single array unless the matrix is a square matrix.
If none, what is the minimum amount of additional memory needed??

EDIT: 
I have already tried all flavors of

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) {
  for(int j=0;j<i;++j) {
     var swap = m[i][j];
     m[i][j] = m[j][i];
     m[j][i] = swap;
  }
}
```

And it is not correct. In this specific example, `m` doesnt even exist. In a single line 
matrix `mat[i][j] = mat[i*m + j]`, where `trans[j][i]  = trans[i*n + j]`

Comment: It's possible, but nontrivial. Wikipedia has the answer, as usual. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Comment: [Some time ago I asked a similar question without knowing the correct term](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3009379/237483)

Comment: Thanks Harold! I am going to work out an implementation and post it here.

Comment: I have removed my answer, because it's not correct.

Comment: @close-voters In which way is this question not constructive?

Comment: interesting. I suppose you would need this sometimes. I would probably just keep the matrix the same and swap i&j when doing lookups.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Inspired by the [Wikipedia - Following the cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition#Non-square_matrices%3a_Following_the_cycles) algorithm description, I came up with following C++ implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <iterator>  // std::ostream_iterator
#include <algorithm> // std::swap (until C++11)
#include <vector>

template<class RandomIterator>
void transpose(RandomIterator first, RandomIterator last, int m)
{
    const int mn1 = (last - first - 1);
    const int n   = (last - first) / m;
    std::vector<bool> visited(last - first);
    RandomIterator cycle = first;
    while (++cycle != last) {
        if (visited[cycle - first])
            continue;
        int a = cycle - first;
        do  {
            a = a == mn1 ? mn1 : (n * a) % mn1;
            std::swap(*(first + a), *cycle);
            visited[a] = true;
        } while ((first + a) != cycle);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    transpose(a, a + 8, 4);
    std::copy(a, a + 8, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

The program makes the in-place matrix transposition of the 2 × 4 matrix

```cpp
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
```

represented in [row-major ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` into the 4 × 2 matrix

```cpp
0 4
1 5
2 6
3 7
```

represented by the row-major ordering `{0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7}`.

The argument `m` of `transpose` represents the rowsize, the columnsize `n` is determined by the rowsize and the sequence size. The algorithm needs `m` × `n` bits of auxiliary storage to store the information, which elements have been swapped. The indexes of the sequence are mapped with the following scheme:

```cpp
0 → 0
1 → 2
2 → 4
3 → 6
4 → 1
5 → 3
6 → 5
7 → 7
```

The mapping function in general is:

> idx → (idx × n) mod (m × n - 1) if idx < (m × n), idx → idx otherwise

We can identify four cycles within this sequence: `{ 0 }`, `{ 1, 2, 4 }`, `{3, 5, 6}` and `{ 7 }`. Each cycle can be transposed independent of the other cycles. The variable `cycle` initially points to the second element (the first does not need to be moved because `0 → 0`). The bit-array `visited` holds the already transposed elements and indicates, that index 1 (the second element) needs to be moved. Index 1 gets swapped with index 2 (mapping function). Now index 1 holds the element of index 2 and this element gets swapped with the element of index 4. Now index 1 holds the element of index 4. The element of index 4 should go to index 1, it is in the right place, transposing of the cycle has finished, all touched indexes have been marked visited. The variable `cycle` gets incremented till the first not visited index, which is 3. The procedure continues with this cycle till all cycles have been transposed.

Comment: this is indeed correct... but I cannot figure out the complexity (bad cases are order of O((mn)^3/2) )

Comment: To cite Wikipedia: "the known algorithms have a worst-case linearithmic computational cost of O(MN log MN) at best"

Comment: yours is still much higher... anyway, it is good as an answer

Comment: This answer is not correct for transposing 6 x 2 (or 2 x 6) matrix.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thank you for your test. I have corrected the algorithm. Originally I tried to implement it without the need of auxiliary storage.

Comment: @UmNyobe：about Christian Ammer's answer, with aggregate analyse the time complexity is indeed O(mn), for every element is moved only once and every element is checked only once to see if it is visited, what's your opion?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this using very large arrays on a 32-bit system? For some peculiar reason, when I use around a 4000000 char array on a 32-bit system it always blocks and never progresses. On a 64-bit it works perfectly. Very weird. Maybe a bug? Has anyone looked at the assembly?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that the task is set uncorrectly. If you would meant by "the same place" use of the same matrix, it is a correct task. But when you are talking about writing down to the same area in memory, " the matrix is represented as a single array of size m*n", you have to add *how* is it represented there. Otherwards it is enough to change nothing except the function that reads that matrix - simply swap indexes in it.

You want to transpose the matrix representation in memory **so, that the reading/setting function for this matrix by indexes remains the same**. Don't you?

Also, we can't write down the algorithm not knowing, is the matrix written in memory by rows or by columns. OK, let's say **it is written by rows**. Isn't it?

If we set these two lacking conditions, the task becomes correct and is not hard to be solved.

Simply we should take every element in the matrix by linear index, find its row/column pair, transpose it, find another resulting linear index and put the value into the new place. The problem is that the transformation is autosymmetric only in the case of square matrices, so it really could not be done in site.  Or it could, if we find the whole index transformation map and later use it on matrix.

*Starting matrix A:*
    m- number of rows
    n- number of columns
    nm - number of elements
    li - linear index
    i - column number
    j - row number

*resulting matrix B:*
    lir - resulting linear index

*Transforming array trans*

```
//preparation
for (li=0;li<nm;li++){
    j=li / n;
    i=li-j*n;
    lir=i*m+j;
    trans[li]=lir;
}

// transposition
for (li=0;li<nm;li++){
   cur=li;
   lir=trans[cur];
   temp2=a[lir];
   cur=lir;
   while (cur!=li){
      lir=trans[cur];
      temp1=a[cur];
      a[cur]=temp2;
      temp2=temp1;
      check[cur]=1;
      cur=lir;
   }
}
```

Such auto transposing has sense only if there are heavy elements in cells.

It is possible to realize trans[] array as a function.

Comment: same place = same memory;transpose = transpose data itself, not access; mn = row1|row2|...|rown = written by rows; So far you have stated the problem correctly. Now your algorithm is incorrect, as I stated I already tried what you proposed. try it with [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ie in memory [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: I have used this algorithm in a prog that was used by thousands of people. Simply somewhere you have an error. Put the code here. ( I do not insist that I haven't and error *in the code* - had written by memory)

Comment: it only works for square matrices. Even the generic idea behind the algorithm

Comment: Look the edited answer, please. You was right, the previous really worked for square matrices only.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this efficiently in the general case requires some effort.  The non-square and in- versus out-of-place algorithms differ.  Save yourself much effort and just use [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/faq/section3.html#transpose).  I previously prepared [a more complete write up](http://agentzlerich.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-fftw-for-in-place-matrix.html), including sample code, on the matter.