# Transpose matrix stored in a 1-dimensional array without using extra memory

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In-place transposition of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227747/in-place-transposition-of-a-matrix)

Recently attended an Technical Written Interview. Came through the following question.

I have an array as say

```
testArray = {a1,a2,a3,...an,b1,b2,b3,....bn,c1,c2,c3,.....,cn}
```

I need to sort this array as `

```
testArray = {a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,.....,an,bn,cn}
```

Constraint is I should not use extra memory, should not use any inbuilt function.
Should write complete code, it can be in any language and can also use any data structure.

eg:

```
Input: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, n = 3

Output: {1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9}
```

I could not get any solution within the constraint, can anyone provide solution or suggestion?

Comment: I might be nit picking, but doesn't swapping already need extra memory?

Comment: use quicksort algo , no space overhead :)

Comment: Actually I wouldn't call this "sorting", it's much more of a re-ordering process (as the desired order of the elements doesn't depend on the values but on the initial position in the array).

Comment: @Alex: not if you use that ugly XOR swapping trick.

Comment: @Alex not necessarily. You can use the XOR trick.

Comment: @joachimSauer I was thinking about forcing the swapping into a register, but that wouldn't be language agnostic.

Comment: It looks like you try to sort on identifier names used to build up the array, which might not be possible as that information is not present in the array later on.

Comment: I do not think your input/outputs are correct. I would understand the question as "compare first by second character, then by first".

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Yes its more of reordering. You can use any language, but preferably C++ since we need to implement everything. its purely coding. No algorithms and pseudocode will be considered.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Entirely false. Quicksort is O(log *n*) in space.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hmm I seem wrong at it since , it doesn't req any space for holding elements of array but holding left, right, pivot while going throw recursive calls.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis That's the classic pitfall with Quicksort---forgetting to account for stack allocation.

Comment: I think this question is about swapping elements in the array rather than sorting them. {a1, a2, a3... } is sorted, so it needs to be moved into proper positions in the array.

Comment: **No extra memory** seems like a very harsh constraint. Probably, only O(1) extra memory was intended. If one is being strict, no extra memory would mean that you are not allowed to declare loop counter variables.

Comment: Yes, constraint was very harsh, since there are only two questions and 3 hours to solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a matrix transpose operation. And there is even a problem and solution for [in-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition) on Wikipedia.

No extra space is impossible, since you need to at least go through the array. `O(1)` additional memory is possible, with heavy penalty on the time complexity.

The solution is built on follow-the-cycle algorithm in the Wikipedia page: for each cell, we will find the cell with the smallest index in the cycle. If the cell with the smallest index is greater than or equal (>=) to the index of the current cell, we will perform chain swapping. Otherwise, we ignore the cell, since it has been swapped correctly. The (loosely analyzed) upper bound on time complexity can go as high as O((MN)<sup>2</sup>) (we go through M * N cells, and the cycle can only be as long as the total number of cells).

Comment: +1 for reading the question instead of just the title

Comment: We all read the bit about not using any extra memory :)

Answer (score 4):

## Impossibility

It is impossible to implement this algorithm without extra use of memory and an arbitrary length because you need a an iterator to traverse the list and that takes up space.

## Finding the right indices to swap

For fixed lengths of the array and fixed *n* you can use a matrix transpose algorithm.
and in order to swap the elements y

The algorithm you are looking for is a matrix transpose algorithm.
so you have to swap every element exactly once iterating through it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

basically you have to swap the *m* -th element in the *n* - th component with the *n* - th element in the *m* -th component. This can be done by a double loop.

```
m = length(array)/n;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < n;  j++)
  {
     index_1 = i * m + j;
     index_2 = j * m + i
     swap(index_1, index_2);
  }
```

**Note**: For fixed *m* and *n* this loop can be completely unrolled and therefore *m, i, j* can be replaced by a constant.

## Swaping without Memory consumption

In order to swap every element without using extra space you can use the XOR swap algorithm as pointed out in the comments:

```
X := X XOR Y
Y := Y XOR X
X := X XOR Y
```

Comment: and thanks for keeping my mind busy in the bathtub!

Comment: This is answer is too fluffy and barely touch on the real implementation.

Comment: @nhahtdh feel free to edit the answer to a less fluffy solution. I thought that implementing it in a real language doesn't make the trick. the part of not using extra memory is more important, and looking at all the places where memory could be used. not just in the swap.

Comment: @nhahtdh http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_131.html here is a link to implement the loop unrolling at compiletime in C++. I guess the implementation itself would be less readable than the pseudo code. as it involves transforming the loops into a single tail-recursion. (if you set a bounty of +100 I implement it tonight)

Comment: It is not as simple as it seems, since there are cycles when you calculate the index to swap (a chain of several positions that swaps with each other).

Comment: @nhahdh: ah. I see I just implemented it for square matrices. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to swap two numbers (a and b) without using a temporary variable is like this:

```
  b = b + a;
  a = b - a;
  b = b - a;
```

If you write that in a function, then you're part of the way there. How you keep track of which variable to swap within the arrays without using a temporary variable eludes me right now.

Bear in mind voters: he doesn't actually need to sort the array, just swap the right values.

**Edit: this will work with large values in Java (and in C/C++ unless you turn on some very aggressive compiler optimisations - the behaviour is undefined but [defaults to sane](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Signed-Overflow-Examples.html)). The values will just wrap around.**

Second edit - some (rather untested) code to flip the array around, with I think 4 integers over the memory limit. It's while technically massively unthreadsafe, but it would be parallelisable just because you only access each array location once at most:

```
static int[] a = {1,2,3,4,
                  5,6,7,8,
                  9,10,11,12,
                  13,14,15,16};

static int n = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length/n; i++)     //  1 integer
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)          //  1 integer
            if(j > i)
                swap(i*n+j, j*n+i);
}

static void swap(int aPos, int bPos)        //  2 integers
{
    if(a[aPos] != a[bPos])
    {
        a[bPos] = a[aPos] + a[bPos];
        a[aPos] = a[bPos] - a[aPos];
        a[bPos] = a[bPos] - a[aPos];
    }
}
```

Apologies if this misunderstands the question; I read it carefully and couldn't work out what was needed other than this.

Comment: if numbers are very big then b will overflow and this fails then

Comment: Just try it with `char a = 150; char b = -150;`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall chars are unsigned, what sense is there in your example?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, make them any other type and cause overflow by bigger numbers, doesn't really matter. And why should chars be unsigned?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Test this then: `int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE, b = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1;
    System.out.println("a " + a + " , b " + b);
    b = b + a;
    a = b - a;
    b = b - a;
    System.out.println("a " + a + " , b " + b);`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, (in case you were talking abuot java) sorry I was talking about C++, since the question is also C++ tagged

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall So test it with C++. Same resutls. Java has exactly the same semantics for signed ints as C++.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

For more information about available algorithms, go to [Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) page.

Comment: From the page you just linked: "so the entire sort can be done with only O(log *n*) additional space. Log *n* > 0.

Comment: Yes, and the entire sentence is "Quicksort **can** be implemented with an in-place partitioning algorithm, so the entire sort can be done with only O(log n) additional space."

Comment: How are you going to implement a comparison function based on the item's initial position in the array without using extra memory?

Comment: Do you then claim that the full sencence changes the meaning of my statement?

Comment: I mean that Quicksort is an in-place algorithm, then no more array creation is required. So, depending on what Gokul Nath said, i guess that its main constraint is to avoid creating more arrays than the input array itself.

Comment: No, the request is to "not use extra memory". Quicksort **does use extra memory**. BTW notice that the question is not at all about sorting, anyway.

Comment: You're right, intermediate variables like pivot index will be stored in call stack. I though the main constraint will be on the heap.