# Transpose matrix stored in 1-D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, transpose

Come with a problem of matrix transpose: the matrix (r x c) is stored in a 1-D array; transpose this matrix without using any extra bulk memory. Directly operation on the original memory. You can use some simple variable, but no bulk memory comparable to the original matrix.

For example:

```
0 1 2      0 3
3 4 5 ---> 1 4
           2 5
```

In memory, it means

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5] ---> [0 3 1 4 2 5]
```

Can anyone help with the algorithm? C++, Python or Pseudo-code is good.

Comment: Hint `a[i][j]` = `a[i*col + j]`

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Please show me the codes. You might think it too simple.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a programming assignment or you need this for a real world application, but an alternative to actually transposing the matrix is to store a isTransposed flag with the matrix and swap the indices whenever you retrieve an element if the flag is set.

Comment: I think this is the one you are looking for probably. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500993/transpose-matrix-stored-in-a-1-dimensional-array-without-using-extra-memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-place transposition of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227747/in-place-transposition-of-a-matrix)

Comment: venkat and yola, thanks a lot!