# Efficiently inserting column/row into a matrix stored in row/col-major vector in-place

Tags: c++, matrix, insert

It's not hard to efficiently insert row or column into a matrix stored in a row-
 or col-major (respectively) vector. The problem of inserting row into a col-major vector or column into a row-major vector is slightly more interesting.

For example, given a 2x3 matrix stored in row-major in vector:

```
1 2 3    <=>    1 2 3 4 5 6 
4 5 6
```

and a column `7 8` that is inserted before after column 1 in the original matrix, we get:

```
1 7 2 3    <=>    1 7 2 3 4 8 5 6 
4 8 5 6
```

[Inserting a row into a col-major vector is similar.]

The sample setup in C++:

```
auto m = 2; // #rows
auto n = 3; // #cols
// row-major vector
auto x = std::vector<double>{1,2,3,4,5,6};

auto const colIndex = 1;
auto const col = std::vector<double>{7,8};
// insert column {7,8} into the 2nd position
// =>{1,7,2,3,4,8,5,6}
```

There could be various options to achieve this algorithmically and in C++, but we're looking for the efficiency and scalability to large matrices and multiple inserts.

The first obvious option that I can think of is to use `std::vector<double>::insert` to insert new elements to the correct positions:

```
//option 1: insert in-place
x.reserve(m*(n+1));
for(auto i = 0; i < col.size(); i++)
   x.insert(begin(x) + colIndex + i * (n + 1), col[i]);
```

, which is valid but *extremely* slow even for moderate data sizes because of the resizing and shifting on each iteration.

Another, more direct option is to create another vector, populate all the columns in the ranges `[0,colIndex),colIndex,(colIndex,n+1]`, and swap it with the original vector:

```
// option 2: temp vec and swap
{
    auto tmp = std::vector<double>(m*(n+1));

    for(auto i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(auto j = 0; j < colIndex; j++)
            tmp[j + i * (n + 1)] = x[j + i * n];

        tmp[colIndex + i * (n + 1)] = col[i];

        for(auto j = colIndex + 1; j < n + 1; j++)
            tmp[j + i * (n + 1)] = x[(j - 1) + i * n];
    }

    std::swap(tmp, x);
};
```

This is *much* faster than the option 1, but requires extra space for the matrix copy and iterating over all elements.

Are there any other ways to achieve this that would beat the above in speed/space or both?

Example code on ideone: https://ideone.com/iXrPfF

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried your first option, but first calling [`std::vector::reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) so that it only has to reallocate once? There will still be duplicate shifting (which can be optimized out). I'm crafting an answer to address that part of it.

Comment: @TypeIA good point - thanks. I did try it - the improvement is negligible even for matrices of size like 100k*10k. But it's still better, you're right - I'll edit.

Comment: why are you starting your shifting at the front of the vector?  Start it at the back then you only have to shift things once, and it becomes a single for loop rather than one with nested for loops

Comment: Generally it makes more sense to figure out which container to use based on what needs to be done with it, instead of picking a container first, and then figure out how to what needs to be done in the most efficient manner. If it's necessary to have both efficient row and column insertions into a matrix, then a one-dimension vector is not the right container.  It's going to be hard to figure out how to implement this efficiently. One will need a fairly complicated, non-linear, container to do this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks - true story. however this insert functionality is just one of many and not the most important operation. there're other linear algebra routines that require contiguous memory, so array/vector is pretty much the only choice here

Comment: @UKMonkey thanks. Are you talking about option 1 or two: shifting only happens in the first option and the total #shifts would be the same regardless of where to start; nested loops are in option 2 but i'm not sure what's the benefit of starting from the back there

Answer (score 3):

This version is likely to be much faster, especially at scale, and could be the basis for further micro-optimization (if [*and only if*] really necessary):

```
// one-time reallocation of the vector to get space for the new column
x.resize(x.size() + col.size());

// we'll start shifting elements over from the right
double *from = &x[m * n];
const double *src = &col[m];
double *to = from + m;

size_t R = n - colIndex; // number of cols left of the insert
size_t L = colIndex;     // number of cols right of the insert

while (to != &x[0]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < R; ++i) *(--to) = *(--from);
    *(--to) = *(--src); // insert value from new column
    for (size_t i = 0; i < L; ++i) *(--to) = *(--from);
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/z2MwbM)

This doesn't require any temporary allocation and aside from possible micro-optimizations of the loop it's probably about as fast as it gets. To understand how it works, we can start by observing that the bottom-right element of the original matrix is being shifted `m` elements to the right in the source vector. Working backwards from the last element, at some point a value from the inserted column vector gets inserted, and subsequent elements from the source vector are now shifted `m - 1` only elements to the right. Using that logic we simply construct a 3-phase loop that works from right to left on the source array. The loop iterates `m` times, once for each row. The three phases of the loop, corresponding to its three lines of code, are:

1. Shift row elements that are "to the right" of the insertion point.
2. Insert the row value from the new column.
3. Shift row elements that are "to the left" of the insertion point (shifting one less place than in phase 1).

There's also serious room for improvement in the naming of the variables, and the algorithm should certainly be encapsulated in its own function with proper input parameters. One possible signature would be:

```
void insert_column(std::vector<double>& matrix,
    size_t rows, size_t columns, size_t insertBefore,
    const std::vector<double>& column);
```

From here there's further room for improvement in making it generic using templates.

And from there, you might observe that the algorithm has possible application beyond matrices. What's really happening is that you're "zippering" two vectors together with a skip and an offset (i.e., starting at element `i`, insert an element from `B` into `A` after every `n`'th element).

Comment: huh, interesting.. i'll think about this and test it as well. will let you know. thanks!

Comment: I did some quick testing and it seems that your approach is very slightly faster for smaller data and slower for large data. E.g. for 100k*10k matrix, option 2 from my question takes ~25sec, and yours 39sec (averaged across several runs.) Perhaps compiler optimizations and things like that can play a role here too. I'll do more tests and post results. Your solution is interesting anyways even b/c it's in-place without extra space.

Answer (score 0):

so what I would go with is something like (completely untested (tm))

```
x.resize(x.size() + col.size());

for (size_t processed = 0; processed < col.size(); ++processed) {
    // shift the elements for row n (starting at the end) 
    // to their new location
    auto start = x.end()-(processed+1) * rowSize;
    auto end = start + rowSize;
    auto middle = end - (col.size()-processed);
    std::rotate(start, middle, end);

    // replace one of the default value items to be the new value
    x[x.size()- rowSize*(1+processed)] = col[col.size()-processed-1];
}
```

The idea being that you go from
`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`  & adding `[a,b,c]`

Resize:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,x,x,x]`

First loop shift:
`[1,2,3,4,x,x,x,5,6]`

First loop replace
`[1,2,3,4,x,x,c,5,6]`

Second loop shift
`[1,2,x,x,3,4,c,5,6]`

and so on.

Since std::rotate is linear, and each item only ever gets moved once; this should also be linear.

This differs to your option #1 in that every time you inserted, you have to move everything afterwards; meaning that the last x elements are shifted col.size() times.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate solution can be transpose followed by insertion and transpose again. However, the in-place transpose in non-trivial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition). See the implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320349

Comment: thanks, it's a valid approach but I don't think that 2*transpose with insertion is better than any of the above solutions by any metric