# Function to print Matrix in abstract data type

Tags: c, abstract-data-type

In the matrix. c I have

```
struct matrix{
    int row;
    int col;
    int *a;
};

Matrix* allocateMemory(int m, int n) {
    Matrix* mat = (Matrix*) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

    if (mat == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
mat->row = m;
mat->col = n;
mat->a = (int*)calloc(m*n, sizeof(int));
return m;
}
```

While in the matrix.h I have

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_INCLUDED
#define MATRIX_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct matrix Matrix;

Matrix* allocateMemory(int m, int n);  
//...
int printMatrix(Matrix* mat); 

int transpose(Matrix* mat); 

#endif // MATRIX_H_INCLUDED
```

I am working in an ADT for matrices but I stucked in the print function. I would like to create a function

```
int printMatrix(Matrix* mat)
```

So in the main.c I would have something like

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++){           
        printf("%d    ", printMatrix(mat));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It means I want the printf in the main, not in the function, but I just could do this

```
void printMatrix(Matrix* mat){
int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < mat->row; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < mat->col; j++){
            k = i*mat->col + j;
            printf("%d   ", mat->a[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

It does print the matrix, but it doesn't seem to be right. It is the same for the transpose matrix function, it does print the transpose matrix correctly, but I would like an

```
int transpose(Matrix* mat)
```

So I would use the function printMatrix in the main to print the transpose, but I just could do

```
void transpose(Matrix* mat){
int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < mat->col; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < mat->row; j++){
            k = j*mat->row + i;
            printf("%f     ", mat->a[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }    
}
```

> How can I create the int function to print the matrix?
>
> I am still studying ADT, but what would be my lack of understanding so I couldn't do the function?

Comment: You could add a small main to make things easier, but I'd say that your printMatrix() function is fine. transpose() on the other hand should be called printTransposed() or actually transpose its argument, which you could then print with printMatrix()

Comment: @JackLilhammers That's true. But I just called transpose() because I intended to do a function to transpose the matrix, and in the main.c use the function printMatrix() to print the transposed matrix.

Comment: _Side note:_ You need `typedef struct matrix { ... } Matrix;` to make it compile because you're using `Matrix` everywhere. Also, _never_ put spaces around the arrow operator (i.e. `->`)--no experienced programmer does that. So, change all (e.g.) `mat ->row` into `mat->row`

Comment: @CraigEstey The typedef struct matrix Matrix; is in the matrix.h, I will fix the arrows, thank you.

Comment: I agree with _Jack_ that your print function is fine. So, do you want to _actually_ transpose your matrix with `transpose`? Or, do you just want to print it transposed? _If_ you want produce a transposed matrix, you can't do it "in-place" (i.e.) `transpose` would either need to take _two_ arguments (e.g.) `void transpose(Matrix *matout,Matrix *matin)` or it would need to allocate/create a new matrix struct (e.g.) `Matrix *transpose(Matrix *matin) { Matrix *matout = allocateMemory(matin->row,matin->col); ... return matout; }` Either way, `transpose` would need to copy the elements [transposed]

Comment: You _could_ perform an in-place transposition, but it's not easy. In case you'd like to try, you may want to look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320349/10996546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

A few more style tips ...

Do *not* cast the return of `malloc` [et. al.]

A bit more idiomatic is (e.g.):

```
Matrix *mat = malloc(sizeof(*mat));
```

I realize that in school, they teach the use of (e.g.) `i, j, k`, but try to use more descriptive names (e.g) `row, col, off`.

And, make the arguments descriptive as well:

```
Matrix *allocateMemory(int row,int col)
```

---

Here's a refactored version [with some style cleanups]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matrix {
    int row;
    int col;
    int *a;
} Matrix;

Matrix *
allocateMemory(int row, int col)
{
    Matrix *mat = malloc(sizeof(*mat));

    if (mat == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    mat->row = row;
    mat->col = col;

    mat->a = calloc(row * col, sizeof(*mat->a));
    if (mat->a == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    return mat;
}

void
printMatrix(Matrix *mat)
{
    int row, col, off;

    for (row = 0; row < mat->row; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < mat->col; col++) {
            off = (row * mat->col) + col;
            printf("%d   ", mat->a[off]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void
matrix_fill(Matrix * mat)
{
    int row, col, off;
    int val = 1;

    for (row = 0; row < mat->row; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < mat->col; col++) {
            off = (row * mat->col) + col;
            mat->a[off] = val++;
        }
    }
}

void
transpose_copy(Matrix *matout,Matrix *matin)
{
    int row, col;
    int inoff, outoff;

    for (row = 0; row < matin->row; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < matin->col; col++) {
            inoff = (row * matin->col) + col;
            outoff = (col * matout->col) + row;
            matout->a[outoff] = matin->a[inoff];
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

Matrix *
transpose_new(Matrix *matin)
{
    Matrix *matout = allocateMemory(matin->col,matin->row);

    transpose_copy(matout,matin);

    return matout;
}

int
main(void)
{

    Matrix *matin = allocateMemory(2,3);
    matrix_fill(matin);

    printf("Original:\n");
    printMatrix(matin);

    Matrix *matout = transpose_new(matin);

    printf("Transposed:\n");
    printMatrix(matout);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
Original:
1   2   3
4   5   6

Transposed:
1   4
2   5
3   6
```