# Array movement from a1,..,an,b1,..,bn to a1,b1,..,an,bn

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

Today, I met a question which is really puzzled me

**Question**

I have array just like:`arr[a1, a2, a3....an, b1, b2, b3.....bn]`, how to move the elements of the array to transfer it into `arr[a1, b1, a2, b2......an,bn]`, And you should do the movement in-place（`space complexity should be constant`）.

I tried my best to think it over and get an ugly algorithm just like bubble-sort:

```
b1 moves forward by n - 1;
b2 moves forward by n - 2;
.
.
bn-1 moves forward by 1;
```

But the time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>), who can give me a better algorithm?
I find another better method just like quick-Sort:

```
First we swap the element from a(n/2) to a(n) with the elements from b1 to b(n/2);now we get two independent sub problems,So we can solve it by recursion.
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n) 
the time complexity is O(nlgn)
```

here are whole codes:

```
void swapArray(int *arr, int left, int right)
{
    int mid = (left + right) >> 1;
    int temp = mid + 1;
    while(left <= mid)
    {
        swap(arr[left++], arr[temp++]);
    }
}
void arrayMove(int *arr, int lb, int le, int rb, int re)
{
    if(le - lb <= 0 || re - rb <= 0)
        return;
    int mid = (lb + le + 1) >> 1;
    int len = le - mid;
    if(rb + len >= re)
    {
        swapArray(arr, mid + 1, rb);
    }
    else
    {
        swapArray(arr, mid, rb + len);
    }
    arrayMove(arr, lb, mid - 1, mid, le);
    arrayMove(arr, rb, rb + len, rb + 1 + len, re);
}
```

Comment: Hint: [In-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to swap array-elements to transfer the array from a column-like into a row-like representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009379/how-to-swap-array-elements-to-transfer-the-array-from-a-column-like-into-a-row-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After dabbling and experimenting/stumbling a little, I think I'm beginning to understand, although the math is still hard for me. I think it goes something like this:

Determine the permutation cycles of the transposition (this can be done during or before the actual data transfer). The formula, `to = 2*from mod (M*N - 1), where M = 2, N = array length / 2`, can be used to find the index destinations (permutation). (I reduced the formula for this question since we know M = 2.) A marker of visited indexes can help determine the start of the next cycle (technically speaking, one could use the cycle calculations rather than a bitset as a marker, keeping only the next cycle-start in memory). A temporary variable holds the data from the start address until the cycle-end.

Altogether, that could mean two temporary variables, the cycle calculations, and one move in-place per array element.

For example:

```
arr          = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
destinations:  0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9

start = 1, tmp = arr[1]    

cycle start
5->1, 7->5, 8->7, 4->8, 2->4, tmp->2
cycle end

not visited - 3

start = 3, tmp = arr[3]

cycle start
6->3, tmp->6
cycle end

Transposition complete.
```

Any questions?
Feel free to ask and please visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Comment: I was thinking about a similar solution but couldn't solve the problem of constant space complexity. This solution has also linear space complexity because you have to save if an entry has been visited.

Comment: This does take less memory than copying everything to a different array, because you only need one additional bit per element for the visited array. But as Nico says it's still linear space complexity.

Comment: First we swap the element from a(n/2) to a(n) with the elements from b1 to b(n/2);now we get two independent sub problems,So we can solve it by recursion.
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)
the time complexity is O(nlgn)

Comment: @NicoSchertler I think the second example here uses the cycles without a bitset, although I don't understand how http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition#C

Comment: The linked example determines if an element has been already visited by following the cycle once more. If there is an element in the cycle that is before the current element, we already visited the current one. Not optimal in my opinion; I would definitely prefer the bit flag. But, although it might be one of the best solutions, it has linear space complexity and is therefore no solution for this question.

Comment: @NicoSchertler That's exactly what I just came up with myself!

Comment: @NicoSchertler I disagree - two temporary variables and one move in-place per element is O(1) space.

Comment: @interjay please see our comments and my (small) update if you like.

Comment: hey everyone I implemented another method to solve this question, you can see the codes in my question if you like!

Comment: @minicaptain great...so you improved the original time-complexity and found an original way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short code in Python that does this:

```
n = 4
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
result = a[:n]
for index in range(n):
    result.insert(index*2 + 1, a[n+index])
print result  #  prints ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2', 'a3', 'b3', 'a4', 'b4']
```

Comment: `insert` is still in Ο(n). With n/2 operations your algorithm is also in Ο(n^2).

Comment: space complexity should be constant

Comment: @interjay since most algorithms would need memory space for calculations such as `*2 + 1`, how does one decide when it is no longer "in-place"? (sincerely, not sarcastic)

Comment: @groovy: in-place means that it can only use O(1) additional memory except for the original data structure. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm. This means there is no problem performing simple calculations, but you can't allocate an additional data structure like `result` in this answer.

Comment: This method can work more quickly!First we swap the element from a(n/2) to a(n) with the elements from b1 to b(n/2);now we get two independent sub problems,So we can solve it by recursion.
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n) 
the time complexity is O(nlgn)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best way, because it doesn't directly answer your question but Why don't you just simply map the new indices of the elements to the old indices of the elements?

```
old_array: [a1, a2, a3....an, b1, b2, b3.....bn]
=>
lookup: [0 n 1 n+1 2 n+2 ... n-1 2n-1]
=>
[a1 b1 a2 b2 ... an bn]
```

When you want to grab an element from an index

```
Get(index)
 return old_array[lookup[index]]
End

Get(2) => old_array[lookup[2]] => old_array[1] => a2 | a2 is at index 2
```

Comment: space complexity should be constant

Answer (score 0):

Working Java code for "Array movement from a1,..,an,b1,..,bn to a1,b1,..,an,bn"

```
private static void myTrans(int[] m) {
    int n = (m.length - 1);

    int i = 1;
    for (int start = 1; start < n; start++) {
        int temp = m[start];
        m[start] = m[n / 2 + i];

        for (int j = (n / 2 + i); j > start; j--) {
            m[j] = m[j - 1];
        }

        start++;
        m[start] = temp;
        printArray(m);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void shuffle(char[] arr, int left, int right){
    //center
    int c = (left+right)/2;
    int q = 1 + (left+c)/2;
    for(int k=1,i=q;i<=c;i++,k++){
         //Swap elements
         int temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[c+k];
         arr[c+k] = temp;
    }
    shuffle(arr,left,c);
    shuffle(arr,c+1,right);
}
```

This is will shuffle around center:

1. a1a2a3a4b1b2b3b4 -> a1a2b1b2a3a4b3b4
2. a1a2b1b2 -> a1b1a2b2
3. a3a4b3b4 -> a3b3a4b4

Complexity of this solution will be nlogn

Answer (score 0):

Please check my attempted solution for in-place sorting in Java:

Time complexity: O(N), where N is the length of the array.
Space complexity: O(1)

```
public static void sortSpecialArray(String[] array) {
    sortSpecialArrayUtil(array);
    sortSpecialArrayUtil(array);
}

/**
 * Given an array with ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', ..., 'aN', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', ...,'bN', 'c1'...'cN']
 * sort the array to be a1, b1, c1...
 *
 * O(N) time complexity (derived from O(N * K) below)
 * O(1) space complexity
 */
private static void sortSpecialArrayUtil(String[] array) {
    // O(1) space complexity requires this function to sort the array in-place
    // this can be done using a pointer that keeps track of where we are
    // in the array. The idea is to swap the values in the array to get the element in the right place.
    int n = stripNumber(array[array.length - 1]);
    int charCount = array.length / n;

    // start the loop at index = 1, up until index = array.length - 2
    // ignore those two elements because they're already in the right place
    int lastIndex = array.length - 2;
    String element;
    for (int i = 1; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
        element = array[i];
        swap(array, i, getCorrectIndex(charCount, element));
    }
}

/**
 * Assume that array's element is in format of something like "a1", where there can only be one 'letter' before the number
 * extract number from the string
 *
 * This is done in time O(K), where K is the length of the String
 */
private static int stripNumber(String str) {
    return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, str.length()));
}

private static int getCorrectIndex(int charCount, String element) {
    char c = Character.toLowerCase(element.charAt(0));
    int num = stripNumber(element);

    // the correct index is found by the following formula: index = charDistance + (charCount * (num - 1))
    int charDistance = c - 'a';
    return charDistance + (charCount * (num - 1));
}

private static void swap(String[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    String temp = array[toIndex];
    array[toIndex] = array[fromIndex];
    array[fromIndex] = temp;
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testSortArray() {
    String[] testCase = new String[] { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5" };
    sortSpecialArray(testCase);
    for (String s : testCase) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Suppose the input array is given as **[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3]**, so as per the question we want the output as **[a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3]**. Let me represent the array as 2D matrix
with each row denoting group size of n(n being 3 in this case).

```
Original array
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
c1 c2 c3

What we Want
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c3
```

Did you notice something.Let me tell you output array is actually **transpose** of the input array represented as 2D matrix which can be easily done using constant space.

- Note: You need to develop your logic for breaking this original array into 2D array.

> Implementation [Code](http://ideone.com/rfWTZH)

Comment: Doing an in-place transposition is not "easily done" as you claim. It's only easy for square matrices, otherwise it's quite complicated. All your answer does is reformulate the question without giving an actual solution.

Comment: @interjay are you kidding me!!!! I have already implemented this problem,infact this is one of the Amazon's online test question.

Comment: No, I'm not kidding you. I'm betting your algorithm isn't actually in-place. If it is, post it here.

Comment: As I thought, your implementation isn't [in-place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm). You need to modify the input array without allocating any additional arrays whose size depends on `n`. This makes it a much more difficult problem.

Comment: @interjay well, am I getting it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043778/array-movement-from-a1-an-b1-bn-to-a1-b1-an-bn/18047495#18047495

Comment: I implemented another method to solve this question, the time complexity is O(nlgn), you can see it in my question!