# Merge given array of elements in constant space

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given a array of elements like `[a1,a2,...an, b1,b2,...bn, c1,c2,...cn]` how to merge like `[a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, ... an, bn, cn]` without using extra memory.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow, but two negative votes on my question?? What was that for??

Comment: Without using extra memory, I don't think it can be done in general.  If you have one extra temporary location, it is doable.  Or, you might be able to find a way to do it if we knew the data was a numeric type.

Comment: It is hard, but not impossible (google: "in-place mergsort"). But yes: you need *at least* one memory location just for swapping two others.

Comment: SO is about specific programming issues.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. What did you try? What difficulties did you encounter? What is your question?

Comment: @JensGustedt read the description for the question. I have tried to this using extra memory, but nothing is coming in my mind doing it inorder

Comment: I have found the solution here but unable to understand the solution- https://effprog.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/in-a-given-array-of-elements-like-a1-a2-a3-a4-an-b1-b2-b3-b4-bn-c1-c2-c3-c4-cn-without-taking-a-extra-memory-how-to-merge-like-a1-b1-c1-a2-b2-c2-a3-b3-c/

Comment: @AdityaGoel The algorithm you linked too is awful in terms of extra memory usage.  it stores 3 integers for each function call, and its recursive so you will have 3 times the size of your array on the stack at the deepest recursion.

Comment: I have edited the title to constant space to avoid confusion

Comment: There are more duplicate questions such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043778/array-movement-from-a1-an-b1-bn-to-a1-b1-an-bn), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227747/in-place-transposition-of-a-matrix), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527241/interleave-three-equally-sized-partitions-in-an-array-inplace-in-on-time).

Comment: The title of this thread should be changed, since it's not a merge sort, but as mentioned in the links, swapping array elements from column order to row order, or better yet, it should be called an "in place matrix transpose".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "element" is a signed integer less than half MAXINT, the following lets you swap two integers x and y without using an additional memory cell (source: Prof. Dekker, UvA):

```
x= x + y;    // x is now (x+y)
y= x - y;    // y is now (x+y) - y = old x
x= x - y;    // x is now (x+y) - ((x+y)-y) =old y
```

Comment: It is not just about one swap.

Comment: @AdityaGoel it could be applied to all pairs that needs swapping (subject to stated limitation).

Comment: Can you please elaborate your solution how swapping would be of help here to convert [a1,a2,...an, b1,b2,...bn, c1,c2,...cn] to [a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, ... an, bn, cn]

Comment: or assume elements are two's complement unsigned integer and it always works. So does | x = x ^ y; | | y = x ^ y ; | | x = x ^ y; | .

Comment: @WeatherVane  It's actually very complicated to do it in-place, using just swaps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition